# Rendering performance - image vs. css gradient or box shadow with border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have question about website scroll, animation performance. Is better use in your mobile webapp or website:

- repeating thin image or CSS3 gradient?

or

- repeating image instead box shadow with border?

This is not question about compatibility, I wanna know only performance aspect on scroll, element render and animation.

Because is proved CSS linear gradient is heavier for element rendering than only background-color.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5793586/104380

Answer (score 0):

When you use CSS3 for shadows, gradients, etc. they will be generated by browser on client's end. On the other end any images used for same purpose will be called from server which will be a slower process.

Comment: In that case please elaborate your question.

Comment: I mean this is not about file loading time, this is about element loading time and behavior during scroll and animations with CSS3...